# TCPDF - Remove space between 2 tables (PHP)

Tags: php, tcpdf

I tried to write the table inside a loop by 1 table/loop by using 1 table equal to 1 row.
However, I got a space between 2 tables like attached image below. I try to remove by using css properties like margin,padding are not worked.

[Data is generated in each loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiG6P.png)

How can I remove the space between there table? this is my example code.

```
for ($j=0;$j<count($ins_englishDescriptionOfGoods);$j++){

        $html = <<<EOD
            <table width="100%;" border="1" align="center" style="padding: 5px 1px 5px 2px; border-collapse: collapse;">
                <tr nobr="true">
                    <td width="6%">$ORDER</td>
                    <td width="16%" style="text-align:center;">$GCL_NO</td>
                    <td width="13%" style="text-align:center;">$CONTAINER_NO</td>
                    <td width="23%" style="text-align:left; font-size:12px; line-height:7px;">$ENG_DESC</td>
                    <td width="10%" style="text-align:right;" >$NETWEIGTH</td>
                    <td width="10%" style="text-align:right;">$QTY</td>
                    <td width="10%" style="text-align:right;">$PACKAGE</td>
                    <td width="12%" style="text-align:right;">$FOB</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
EOD;

        $pdf->writeHTML(iconv('TIS-620','UTF-8' ,$html), true, false, false, false, '');
    }
```

Comment: Its probably because of the padding in `<table ... style="padding: 5px 1px 5px 2px; ...">`. What happens when you replace both `5px` to `0`? Why do you create a new table for each row? Create a row for each row instead.

Comment: Because I need to check the total page after I create 1 row, if i create 1 row/loop it means I need to create tag table outside the loop and close the table tag after the loop is done. and writeHTML() at last. So I cannot get the total page before and after I print 1 row.

Comment: It's not about <table ... style="padding: 5px 1px 5px 2px; ..."> this section is enlarge the width and height of each cell only not related with space between table.

Comment: Are there any CSS loaded? Maybe they add margin to the table. *"if i create 1 row/loop it means I need to create tag table outside the loop and close the table tag after the loop is done. and writeHTML() at last"* and why is that impossible/illegal/impractical for you to do? Looks to me like thats the proper way and would probably solve your issue right there.

Comment: ah I understand you, but as i said I need to check the total page after I write 1 row, if i change to your method, I will not able to get totalpage because writeHTML() was called only one time after loop done. So, I need to find another way.

Comment: Whats *"total page"*?

Comment: Total page of pdf file after I called writeHTML(). I want to check that the row that was generated in each loop is break to the new page or not. if it breaked, i will insert the summany row to be a last row of that page before and I will insert the row from the current loop.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this exact same problem just now.
I was able to remove the space between two tables by adding `line-height: -0.8` to the table and adding `line-height: 1.5` to all of the rows in the table:

```
$pdf->html('<p>These two tables are touching each other:</p>');
$pdf->html('<table class="table-border" style="line-height: -0.8"><tbody><tr style="line-height: 1.5"><td>Hello</td></tr></tbody></table>');
$pdf->html('<table class="table-border"><tbody><tr><td>Goodbye!</td></tr></tbody></table>');

$pdf->html('<p>These two tables are not:</p>');
$pdf->html('<table class="table-border" ><tbody><tr><td>Hello</td></tr></tbody></table>');
$pdf->html('<table class="table-border"><tbody><tr><td>Goodbye!</td></tr></tbody></table>');
```

TCPDF doesn't support setting a margin with CSS, so you have to fake it with `line-height` :(